# How do I change the bit depth in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, audio-conversion

I need FFmpeg to grab an audio feed and reencode it to 16-Bit FLAC.

How do I force a 16-Bit FLAC output?

```
./ffmpeg -i http://7359.live.streamtheworld.com:80/CONTINENTALAAC_SC -vn -ac 1 -ar 16000 -acodec flac -map 0 -f segment -segment_list /flac/out.list -segment_time 00:00:12.00 /flac/out%03d.flac
ffmpeg version N-49622-g127ff88 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  6 2013 05:11:38 with gcc 4.6 (Debian 4.6.3-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg-static/32bit --arch=x86_32 --extra-cflags='-m32 -I/root/ffmpeg-static/32bit/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-m32 -L/root/ffmpeg-static/32bit/lib -static' --extra-libs='-lxml2 -lexpat -lfreetype' --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-postproc --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx
  libavutil      52. 17.101 / 52. 17.101
  libavcodec     54. 91.100 / 54. 91.100
  libavformat    54. 61.104 / 54. 61.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 35.101 /  3. 35.101
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[aac @ 0xa163680] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510 microseconds
[aac @ 0xa163680] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, aac, from 'http://7359.live.streamtheworld.com:80/CONTINENTALAAC_SC':
  Duration: 150:52:44.61, bitrate: 29 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 29 kb/s
[flac @ 0xa16ee40] encoding as 24 bits-per-sample
Output #0, segment, to '/flac/out%03d.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.61.104
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 16000 Hz, mono, s32, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac -> flac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=N/A time=00:00:19.22 bitrate=N/A    
video:0kB audio:647kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.003322%
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default, the FFmpeg FLAC encoder takes the bit depth of the original. The bit depth can be changed with the `sample_fmt` option, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i … -c:a flac -sample_fmt s16 output.flac
```

Note that not all formats are supported by every encoder.

For a list of all supported sample formats, run:

```
ffmpeg -sample_fmts
```

See the chapter [Audio Options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options) in the FFmpeg command line documentation.

Comment: This generates output with a bit depth of 4 for me, even when I specify `s16` (bit depth 16). Full command: `ffmpeg -i newwave.wav -c:a adpcm_ima_qt -sample_fmt s16 -ar 22500 newwave.aiff`

Comment: @xjcl The codec you are using only supports 4 bit.

Comment: What's the difference between e.g. `s16` and `s16p`

Comment: This does not work for me. I get " Specified sample format s16 is invalid or not supported"

Comment: @Arete Please make sure you are running a recent version of ffmpeg, and that you are indeed using the `flac` encoder with a FLAC output file. The sample format must be compatible with the chosen encoder.

Comment: @theonlygusti "p" means "planar"; the other formats use "packed" storage. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packed_pixel (Sorry for the late reply, I missed the comment.)

Answer (score 3):

To reduce bit depth to 16 with dithering:

`ffmpeg -i input.flac -acodec flac -af aresample=osf=s16:dither_method=triangular_hp output.flac`

See e.g. https://www.waves.com/audio-dithering-what-you-need-to-know

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, unlike the accepted answer which gave `[aac] Specified sample format s16 is invalid or not supported`.