# How does FFmpeg control bitdepth and bitrate?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

When converting an audio with FFmpeg, there are `-ar` and `-ac` options, which control sampling rate and number of channels, respectively. It also offers `-ab` option, which controls bitrate, but no option to control bitdepth.

Since…

> [bitrate] = [number of channels] * [sampling rate] * [bitdepth]

…does this mean ffmpeg calculates bitdepth from the other 3 parameters?

[Another post](https://superuser.com/questions/547929/how-do-i-change-the-bit-depth-in-ffmpeg) says bitdepth is controlled in the format option. This confused me because the above equation may not hold any more if user sets all 4 parameters.

Could anyone please explain how bitdepth and bitrate work in FFmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the possibilities of **setting the bit depth**: It depends on your source files and on your output-format.

For example, take `pcm_s16le` and `pcm_s24le` - both will render PCM files, but with 16bit / 24bit of bit depth respectively. (You can find this information with `ffmpeg -h encoder=<YOUR_ENCODER>`.)

If you have a format that can take multiple bit depths (such as `libmp3lame`), FFmpeg will by default specify the used value by looking at the source file: So if you take `-c:a libmp3lame` and your input-file has a bit-depth of 16bit, then FFmpeg will use 16 bit. If you have a 32 bit file and want to encode it in a codec that can only hold 16 bit, then FFmpeg will sample it down for you.

But you can also specify it yourself [using `-sample_fmt`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options).

---

As for your **bit rate formula**: FFmpeg, like virtually all other tools, sees the number of audio channels, the bit depth, and the sample rate as fixed values (meaning that they won't change intra-file), while the bit rate is the variable that correlates with the quality of the encoding. That, however, is only true for lossy codecs; that's why re-encoding a WAV-file 200 times won't make a difference, while re-encoding the same files 20 times with a fairly decent MP3-encoder could already lead to unbearable results.

Lossy codecs add quality in your equation: e.g. in MP3, a value of `320k` would accomplish a very good quality, as the encoder would not have to drop much information to stay within the specified values. If you used `-b:a 64k`, the encoder would have to drop many information to achieve the specified bit rate. Encoders will decrease as low as necessary to achieve the bit rate: **Very trivialised and therefore only theoretical examples of information that could be dropped:**

- If combining all frequencies from 8-16kHz into one semi-complex sine-wave would get the encoder to achieve the bit rate, it would do so.
- If deleting every signal below -32dB would do the trick, it would do.

**For some real-world explanation about what information will get dropped, I suggest you start by reading [Wikipedia's article about
   audio-data-compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Audio).**

Comment: So, for lossy codecs, `[bitrate] = compress([number of channels], [sampling rate], [bitdepth])`. The `compress` algorithm can adjust bitrate even if all 3 parameters on the right are fixed. Am I correct?

Comment: I'd say **yes** - all codecs I know of work that way - they basically take a (PCM) bitstream and then compress it as hard as needed to achieve the wanted bit rate.